# "Through" vs. "by" in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

While solving a question, I came in to a situation where I was left wondering between two of the choices. The sentence was:

> Acquisition of certain specific skills can be facilitated **by/through** general
>   awareness, education to novel situations.

According to my understanding *through* sounds more apt. But I am not sure. Could anyone explain the correct usage. In which condition one is preferable over the other?

Answer (score 4):

*By* suggests a direct result:

> The shops were destroyed by flooding.

*Through* suggests an indirect result:

> The shops were repaired through the help of a disaster relief fund.

In some cases we can reasonably consider a result as direct or indirect. In your case we could consider the "general awareness..." as something that directly facilitates the skills you mention, but we could also consider the "general awareness..." as something that is part of a process that in turn facilitates them. As such, but *by* and *through* are justifiable, but like you I would favour *through*.

Comment: @ Jon Hanna: But according to my answer key *by* is the correct answer.

Comment: @Sudhir They presumably believe that it is a direct result then. But then, I'd have said "general awareness **and** education to novel situations" too.

Comment: So here comma makes a huge difference? If yes then how?

Comment: In serial lists, with two items we have "a and b" and then with more than two we have "a, b, and c" or "a, b and c" (both are allowed). This just has "a, b". Alternatively maybe they meant "general awareness education to novel situations", which is also valid but has a different meaning.

Comment: @Sudhir: I'm afraid you've been misled. The answer book you have, and probably the books you are studying from, are incorrect. The example sentence itself is ungrammatical English with **either** preposition, because the phrase _education to novel situations_ is just floating at the end, after a comma, without any way to discern its relation to the rest of the sentence. And even if that had been fixed, the sentence is not idiomatic English; nobody ever says 'facilitated' unless they're reading aloud, and then it's not their grammar but the writer's.

Comment: There's also sometimes a problem with multiple-choice questions in even otherwise good books, where the author writes the question to match the correct answer, but fails to check that the "incorrect" answer is indeed incorrect. I've come across that problem in a variety of fields.